# I can't get count to work in my Python code

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to create a code that will print every number in a range set by the user, and then identify how many numbers in that range are odd numbers and how many are even.

I've tried a few different formats, but I'm very much a beginner and can't seem to nail down where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible.

```
for i in range(x,y+1):
       print(i)

range = (x,y+1)
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
for n in range:
        if   n%2==0:
             count_even = count_even+1
        else:
             count_odd = count_odd+1
print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
```

Currently when I run this, even numbers always comes to 0 and odd to 2.

Answer (score 2):

On line 4 you have:

```
range = (x,y+1)
```

This is the tuple `(x, y+1)` not the range between them. So when you loop through it you are only looping through those two numbers. I assume in your case they are both odd. I would recommend removing that line and starting your second for loop like this:

```
for n in range(x, y + 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

`range` is a builtin function, which returns an iterable from `[start, end)`. You likely want something like:

```
count_odd = 0
count_even = 0
for n in range(x,y+1):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        count_even = count_even + 1
    else:
        count_odd = count_odd + 1

print("Number of even numbers :", count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :", count_odd)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no point for a loop. If your range consists of even elements, then half of values is even and half is odd. If it consists og odd elements and starts from odd value then half+1 is odd and half-1 is even. It starts with even value then it's opposite.

Comment: Since OP mentions s/he's a beginner, this is likely an exercise to learn how to use for loops and ranges.